# How to keep together two mattresses placed side by side?

Tags: comfort, bedroom

I have a sofa bed that can be used either as a single bed, or as a double bed when I unfold the bed frame. I generally use it as a single bed: it is more convenient and allows me to have more space in my small apartment. In that case, I pile two single mattresses up on the bed frame. When I have a guest, I convert the sofa into a double bed, and I put the two mattresses side by side. Unfortunately, that arrangement really requires to sleep still, which is not very suitable for closeness (I mean by that sexual relations but also simply cuddling). Indeed when there is the slightest movement the outer mattress tends to slip out of the bed frame, which doesn’t have a high edge.

That being said, having someone at my place is rare enough to prevent me from buying a spare double mattress.
Is there an easy way to keep the two mattresses together, or at least to prevent the outer mattress to slip out?

Here is the reference for my sofa bed: http://www.ikea.com/fr/fr/catalog/products/00318881/

And my mattresses are those ones: http://www.ikea.com/fr/fr/catalog/products/30272339/

Answer (score 4):

Try Velcro. You can attach a 6-foot strip on the bottom of the long edge of one mattress. On the bottom of the long edge of the other mattress, you sew pieces of Velcro that stick out from the side so they can reach the first mattress. To attach, you set down the mattress with the pieces sticking out, and you lower the other mattress on top of it. The Velcro should keep them from sliding apart.

It also might help to sleep "the other way", so the space between mattresses is crosswise rather than longwise.

[image: sleep orientation]

Comment: You can find self adhesive "hook and loop" fasteners, to avoid having to sew anything.  I would recommend several long strips, to make sure that nothing comes apart.  However, the sound of Velcro coming apart might be distracting during certain, um, activities.

Comment: @computercarguy That's the phrase I was forgetting - "Hook and loop"! I just went with the brand name. And as for the tearing noises the hook and loop fasteners can make, hopefully they'll be secure enough that they don't separate during those, um, activities.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fitted sheet that is made for the size of the two mattresses.
If one of them does not do the work, use one from the bottom up and a second from the top down.

More tips in this [related (but really different) question on Travel Stack Exchange.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/41878/27650)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to avoid unintended "parting of the ways."

Spread a blanket on the bed frame as an under pad. Place the mattresses on top of the blanket beside each other as you wish. Make the double-bed as you normally would

The increased friction of the mattresses on the blanket will keep them from sliding apart as they did when placed directly on the smooth surface of the divan.

For even more "hold," use a strip of rug tape between the blanket and each mattress length-wise near the centre of the bed. The double-sided adhesive tape is made to hold fabrics temporarily and will peel off when no longer desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a mattress wedge,you can find it in [Ikea](https://m.ikea.com/es/en/catalog/products/art/40272353/),as specified in the description it covers the gap between mattresses. I had the same problem and "siggerud" worked pretty well. If the gap is still deep and you still feel uncomfortable you can try to add on it a bottom sheet or a rubberised undersheet (not necessarily ikea's)

Answer (score 0):

I personaly use two long strips of velcro on the bottom of my mattresses (the ones that came with the mattresses to hold them together when rolled up).

They stick to the bottom and hold them together just fine.
[image: no]

Answer (score -1):

You could try a long ratchet strap (aka: tie down) that goes all the way around both mattresses.  You only have to make sure the strap is snug, rather than tight, since getting it too tight might cause an uncomfortable high point where the mattresses meet, or other points in the mattresses where there isn't very good structural rigidity.

This isn't as quick and easy to set up as the hook and loop of BrettFromLA's answer, but it avoids that tearing sound.  On the other hand, if you have the ratchet or hooks in the wrong place, that can rattle/bang against the frame and be noisy as well.